# Get urls of files uploaded through dropbox api saver

Tags: dropbox-api

Can i get preview/direct links to the files in my drop box account after i have uploaded them through saver API of drop box . I am trying is that if user uploads files to drop box account using saver API then the direct links to the recently added files appear on the app with the drop box icon alongside . So the user can download it through my app without having to accessing it from drop box .

Answer (score -1):

No, the Saver doesn't return links to the new files in Dropbox. But if you used the Saver, then you already have URLs for the saved files, so why not just show those? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the scenario.

Comment: Actually what i wanted to achieve was that a user is able to upload a file through saver from his system . But the saver needs a URL of the file . So what i did was i created a temporary folder on my application server which stores the file until the drop box API downloads it to its own server through the URL . Now as soon as its uploaded i need to provide the drop box links on my app .

Comment: What's the use case? (Why wouldn't the user just upload the file directly on dropbox.com or through the client app?) In any case, why can't you use the temporary URL you've created?

Comment: The Use Case is , User uploading a file to the drop box through our app and the links to the uploaded files on drop box should appear on the app to be accessible to other users .and Secondly temporary URL would not be valid . Since its temporary , as soon as drop box server has the file . i'll be deleting the file from temporary folder .